# How to use get() to pass object into function

Tags: r, get

I have a object of class character (in the example 'year') and a object x. Then there is a function that is creating a output containing this character in its name. There are no problems with this.

```
year <- "2022"
vector <- c(1,2,3,4,56)

function_1 <- function(x){
mean_res <- mean(x)
assign(paste0(year,"mean_value"),mean_res,envir=parent.frame())
}

function_1(vector)
```

The name of the first created object is depending on the 'year' object. In this case it is called "2022mean_value". Now I want to pass this object into a second function, WITHOUT hardcoding the objects name. That's were the problem is. I can't get(...) the objects name to put it into a function.

```
function_2 <- function(x){
final_res <- x+43
assign(paste0(year,"final_res"),final_res,envir=parent.frame())
}
```

This is the part I am looking for. The code above is not working, it's just to show you want I want.

```
function_2(get(paste(year,"mean_value"))
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you were to use `paste0` instead of `paste`... but why are you doing it this way? why not use the normal `x <- function_1(...)`

Comment: In addition to @rawr 's hint: `parent.frame()` assigns the object to the *environment* the function was *called from* which is not necessarily the environment the function was *defined in*. Use e.g. `parent.env(environment()))` to hoist objects up one level outside the function ... if you absolutely have to ;-)